# Concatenate multiple empty jq in a unix pipe

Tags: json, command-line, jq

When I pipe json in `jq` I get the correct result:

```
echo '{"foo":"bar"}' | jq
```

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

But when I try to pipe it again to `jq`,

```
echo '{"foo":"bar"}' | jq | jq
```

I get the following message

```
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]

    jq is a tool for processing JSON inputs, applying the
    given filter to its JSON text inputs and producing the
    filter's results as JSON on standard output.
    The simplest filter is ., which is the identity filter,
    copying jq's input to its output unmodified (except for
    formatting).
    For more advanced filters see the jq(1) manpage ("man jq")
    and/or https://stedolan.github.io/jq

    Some of the options include:
     -c     compact instead of pretty-printed output;
     -n     use `null` as the single input value;
     -e     set the exit status code based on the output;
     -s     read (slurp) all inputs into an array; apply filter to it;
     -r     output raw strings, not JSON texts;
     -R     read raw strings, not JSON texts;
     -C     colorize JSON;
     -M     monochrome (don't colorize JSON);
     -S     sort keys of objects on output;
     --tab  use tabs for indentation;
     --arg a v  set variable $a to value <v>;
     --argjson a v  set variable $a to JSON value <v>;
     --slurpfile a f    set variable $a to an array of JSON texts read from <f>;
    See the manpage for more options.
```

How could I fix this?

Some context, this is for some kind of automations where performance is not an issue so it doesn't matter if it goes through some `jq` passes

Answer (score 1):

I was lacking the `.`

```
echo '{"foo":"bar"}' | jq . | jq .
```

Note: Although that fixes it, I don't understand why. Even if `jq` prints to standard output, the following jq not able to read from it.

Comment: Different versions of jq have different "defaults" when no filter is specified.  All versions of jq behave consistently when invoked with the `.` filter explicitly.  Thus one could be forgiven for thinking that it's usually best to specify a filter explicitly.